# Reverse dimension of an xarray

Tags: python, python-xarray, dimension

I have a xarray Dataset with dimensions time, latitude, longitude and pressure levels. The latitude goes from 90° to -90°. But I need them from -90° to 90°. How can I turn around the dimension in a way that also the dimension of the variables are changed?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can use reindex:

```
da.reindex(lat = da.lat[::-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to the .sortby method on your xarray dataset (ds):

`ds = ds.sortby('lat', ascending=True)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.isel()` on the dataset object to return a new dataset object with the latitudes reversed for all of the data arrays.

```
ds = ds.isel(lat=slice(None, None, -1))
```

Note, this can also be done to a specific data array object, but if you assign that data array back to the dataset object, the coordinates will *not* be reversed because it will follow the coordinates as stored in the original dataset object.